# Did Ahsoka physically grow during the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars, ahsoka-tano

Ignoring changes due to out-of-universe evolution in the various video and animation software and technologies etc. used, has Ahsoka's physical stats changed in-universe over the course of the Clone Wars?

When she was first introduced in the Clone Wars movie, she was considered younger than the average newly-apprenticed Padawan. Considering how she behaved at the time, I assumed she was in her early or mid teenage years, so the potential for significant growth due to puberty is high.

Did Ahsoka Tano physically grow over the course of the Clone Wars, and if so are there any sources giving numbers on her biodata that can be used for comparison? Before-and-after numbers need not be from the same source.

Comment: Well, you can _see_ the difference. Before she was shorter, then she got taller and the head thingys grew etc. isn't that what  you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah that's what triggered this question, I just wasn't sure if it's because of evolving art styles/technology or she actually grew for real. So I'm looking for non-aesthetic evidence, such as hard numbers.

Comment: I never thought it was because of technology, but rather to show the characters aging.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes.

One databank [entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20110903030539/http://www.starwars.com/databank/character/ahsokatano/index.html) states her height to be 1.61M, while a later [one](http://www.starwars.com/databank/ahsoka-tano) states her to be 1.7M, showing that her character was purposely made taller.

Comment: Her "*head tails"*? /sigh.

Comment: @Richard "Native to the planet Shili, the Togruta are notable for their striped, horn-like montrals and **head-tails**." - [The official *Star Wars* databank.](http://www.starwars.com/databank/togruta)

Comment: I'm not blaming you. I'm just sighing in general.

Comment: @Richard Happy now?

Comment: Actually yes :-)

Comment: If you are going to discard perspective and foreshortening in the latter image to offer proof that Ahsoka got taller then by the same token, Obi-Wan has shrunk. Additionally, her head is tilted back as she looks up in the first image while it is hung forward and down in the latter making a comparison of where her two forward hanging lekku terminate inconclusive.However, that does not mean you are wrong; just that the proffered evidence is suspect.

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/odrlG.png) is the first scene I could find with both Anakin and Ahsoka from the Clone Wars movie where they seem to be in the same depth from the camera, on level ground and standing erect; [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OUFi8.png) is her final scene with Ani in S05E20 of the Clone Wars TV series under the same set of circumstanses. 0.09m is ~3½ inches. I don't see that much difference from eye level to chest. On the other hand, her lekku **do** seem longer.

Comment: Why did you edit out the pictures?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

To further elaborate on Rogue Jedi's answer, I have some images. Notice the change in lekku (head-tails) length.
[image]

[image]